# The task is removed from cgroup after the exit

Tags: linux, docker, go, cgroups

Here is my test code. I want to write current PID to the `tasks` file:

```
package subsystems

import (
  "io/ioutil"
  "os"
  "path"
  "strconv"
  "testing"
)

func TestSubsystems(t *testing.T) {
  p := "/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/test1"
  f := "tasks"

  err := os.MkdirAll(p, 0644)

  if err != nil {
    t.Log(err.Error())
  }

  pid := os.Getpid()

  if err := ioutil.WriteFile(path.Join(p, f), []byte(strconv.Itoa(pid)), 0644); err != nil {
    t.Failed()
  }
}
```

But when the program exits with code 0, I cannot see anything in `tasks`:

```
root@ubuntu:/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/test1# cat tasks
root@ubuntu:/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/test1# cat tasks
root@ubuntu:/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/test1#
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Of course the `tasks` file is empty - your program creates an empty cgroup, adds itself to it and exits (which removes it from the cgroup). There are no other tasks in the cgroup, so it becomes empty when your program quits.

Comment: That said, please tell us what is the **problem** you are trying to solve (i.e. what do you want to achieve) - the behavior you've described is a correct behavior, not a problem.

Comment: @DanilaKiver Yes, you are right. My question is why I cannot see pid in tasks after process exits. You answer is right.
I want to know where are you learn from about this solution(pid auto removed from tasks after it exists)? Did you learn it from cgroup docs?
Thank you !

Comment: I don't see this in the docs immediately, but the fact that the task is removed from the cgroup when it exits is pretty trivial - Linux has PIDs rotation which means that the PID of the task may be reused after it quits. If the task is not removed from the cgroup on exit, the next task reusing its PID will still be in the same cgroup, which is a problem (what if some task with PID 1234 from container 1 exits and then another task with the same PID spawns in another container, while 1234 is still in first container's cgroups' `tasks`?).

Comment: Instead of documentation - the direct proof: [cgroup_release](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/3b47fd5ca9ead91156bcdf6435279ad0b14a650c/kernel/exit.c#L198) being called on `exit(2)`.

Comment: @DanilaKiver  wowowow, Excellent!, I saw you are active on docker topics. I happened to write a docker like project https://github.com/iamwwc/wwcdocker Thankyou :)

Comment: Upd: it seems like [cgroup_exit](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/3b47fd5ca9ead91156bcdf6435279ad0b14a650c/kernel/exit.c#L892) is more relevant reference, as it is the piece of code which actually [moves the task out of the cgroup](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/3b47fd5ca9ead91156bcdf6435279ad0b14a650c/kernel/cgroup/cgroup.c#L6095).

Comment: Should I wrap our discussion into the answer?

Comment: @DanilaKiver Yes, I will accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've described is not a problem at all — it is a correct behavior:

- you create an empty cgroup;
- you add a task to it;
- the task runs in the cgroup for a while;
- the task exits;
- the task gets removed from the cgroup **due to the previous item**;
- the cgroup is empty again;
- you observe the list of cgroup members and see nothing.

Why this is a correct behavior? Well, the most trivial answer is that there are no reasons for keeping non-existent PID in the list of cgroup members. On the other hand, there are numerous reasons for **not** doing this.

PIDs reuse is one of these reasons which comes to mind first: if some PID does not get removed from the cgroup after the death or the graceful shutdown of the task, any other task which will later reuse this PID (assuming that the cgroup is still alive) will be a member of this group, which, obviously, is not a desired behavior, especially when we speak about containers (e.g. such a behavior may be a reason of privileges gain if we speak about the `devices` cgroup).

As I previously mentioned in the comments, I can't find an explicit description of this behavior in the documentation — probably that's because it feels to be too obvious, but the source code is self-explanatory: the `exit(2)` system call [executes](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/3b47fd5ca9ead91156bcdf6435279ad0b14a650c/kernel/exit.c#L892) `cgroup_exit()` under the hood, and this function [moves the task out of its cgroups](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/3b47fd5ca9ead91156bcdf6435279ad0b14a650c/kernel/cgroup/cgroup.c#L6095).

Comment: Accpeted.This question has solved but another not. https://github.com/iamwwc/wwcdocker/issues/1

Comment: @toffee, the issue you've linked to states that the child process (which should be cgrouped) is alive, but this is not true - it is a [zombie process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process), i.e. it already called `exit(2)` and thus was removed from the cgroup, but it is still visible to you (though with the `<defunct>` mark), because its parent did not collect its exit status. You have to determine why it exits before you want it to do so.

Comment: Yes, I solve it according your commit. you can view latest commit in my issue :).  Thankyou,!! Could I ask for you help when I stuck in?